# Let user reorder buttons in a UIView

Tags: iphone, button, uiview

I have a view in which there are 6 buttons. I want to let user reorder the position of these buttons as I can do in the screen of the iphone with the app icons. The user could drag a button to the position of another button and change its position in the view.
Facebook app has this functionality with its icons too.
Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: ok sorry, where can I accept the answers for my other questions?

Comment: Click on your name to go to your profile, there all your previous questions will be listed.  You can go to each one, select the correct answer (if there is one) and choose accept (it is a check mark)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the Three20 [Launcher](http://three20.info/article/2010-10-21-Launcher).